# Split a column in two based based on variable lenght field

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Hi: I have a table made with rows like this:

```
ID_CATEGORIA CATEGORIA_DRG
------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------
1            001-002-003-543 Craniotomia
2            004-531-532 Interventi midollo spinale
3            005-533-534 Interventi vasi extracranici
4            006 Decompressione tunnel carpale
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
    ID           CATEGORIA           DESCRIZIONE
    ------------ ------------------  --------------------------------------
    1            001-002-003-543     Craniotomia
    2            004-531-532         Interventi midollo spinale
    3            005-533-534         Interventi vasi extracranici
    4            006                 Decompressione tunnel carpale
```

I don't need to alter the table, a 'formatted' query can be enough.

I Think `SUBSTRING()` is the right function for me, but I don't know how to mesaure the lenght of the first (numbers, dash-separated) field.

In Python I'll find that size with `len("005-533-534 Interventi vasi extracranici".split(' ')[0])`', but I don't have idea about how to write it in SQL

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do -

```
SELECT ID_CATEGORIA AS ID ,SUBSTRING(CATEGORIA_DRG,1,CHARINDEX(' ',CATEGORIA_DRG)) as CATEGORIA,SUBSTRING(CATEGORIA_DRG,CHARINDEX(' ',CATEGORIA_DRG),LEN(CATEGORIA_DRG)) AS DESCRIZIONE
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: ...and how is this different from my answer? Except you didn't use subquery.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn - 
firstly - I didn't copy your answer, infact I didn't notice that you had already posted something while I was doing my stuff
secondly - I didn't had to edit my answer, it provided correct answer from the word go
I guess I stand not guilty :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id_categoria ID,
       substring(categoria_drg, 1, idx) CATEGORIA,
       substring(categoria_drg, idx + 1, 1000) DESCRIZIONE
from (
    select id_categoria, categoria_drg, charindex(' ', categoria_drg) idx from my_table
) a
```

It uses `charindex` to detect when the code is finished, because it is followed by first space in the string, which the function finds :)